# combobox onchange with partial update doesn't fire in new document mode

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

In my Custom Control I have SSJS for a combobox onchange event to update an element using partial update.
The event is not fired when I'm in new document mode but fires when in edit mode.

I've tried other combinations such as Full Update, other events but it seems like Partial update is not working when in New Document mode.

Am I missing something here?

Using examples from: [xpageswiki.com](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_Hide_When_on_a_XPage)

Please advice

/Mike

Comment: Which browser are you using? IE?

Comment: Chrome, MSIE & Firefox latest versions Windows

Comment: Could you please post more details about what you are working on? Some source code would be nice, and perhaps the domino version.

Comment: SSJS Code? Or no code? What do you mean with "New Document" mode? Is there a datasource on your page? What are you doing with the referenced XPage Wiki entry "Working with Hide When on an XPage"? Sorry, have no crystal ball here...

Comment: Well, it seems to be some problem with my xPage… If I create a new xPage with similar functionality it works…
I'll do some research…

Comment: If you want to speed up the resolution of your problem, please post the complete source of your custom control.

Comment: I found the problem:
When having required fields on the form and they are not filled in the event will not fire due the JSF phase.
Setting the Server option "Process data without validation" to True will prevent the JSF to validate and continue with the event.

My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having required fields on the form and they are not filled in the event will not fire due the JSF phase. Setting the Server option "Process data without validation" to True will prevent the JSF to validate and continue with the event.

Answer (score 0):

I'll need to see the  block for your radio button from your page's XML source.

These types of issues are sometimes caused by a bad event handler.  In particular, depending on how you use Eclipse, there may be more that one  block due to bugs in DDE.  If you find more than one  block, remove all but one, and try again.  When this happens to me, I normally remove all  blocks, then use the DDE UI to manually add the code and settings back.